# Надо вставить курсы валют и прогноз погоды на сайт

Tags: xml

**Всем привет!**
Мне надо в шапку сайта вставить:
1) Прогноз погоды в градусах Цельсия + рисунок (солнышко, облако и т.д.), без логотипа сайта прогноза погоды; 
2) Курсы валют от НацБанка Кыргызстана.

**Проблемы:**
1) По погоде: везде дают информер со своим логотипом - убрать который не получается. К примеру во вложенной картинке информер от Гисметео.
2) Курс валют надо брать по этому адресу в формате xml - http://www.nbkr.kg/XML/daily.xml
Я нашел подробную инструкцию по взятию нужных данных из xml.файла  http://alexdev.ru/274/
Но вот подключится к нему у меня не получается!
Такая схема подключения не работает: 

$languages = simplexml_load_file("http://www.nbkr.kg/XML/daily.xml");
var_dump($languages); 
?>
Кто-нибудь раньше делал такое? Заранее спасибо!
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Погоду можно парсить через API, просто нужны будут картинки заранее. В API пишут какое состояние и в зависимости от него выводить нужную картинку, а с температурой и так понятно.

Comment: А можно точнее - ссылку где можно взять погоду!

Comment: Насчет курса валют - это подключение срабатывает, если у файла есть расширение  *.php. Но мне надо вставить это код в index.html - Как это сделать? Или никак не получится?

Comment: openweathermap например. Отличный API

Comment: спасибо. гляну.

Comment: Файл можно назвать index.php, и оставить там html код. И он будет как обычный файл index

Comment: Что скажите насчет курса валют - была у Вас такая тема - есть готовые коды конвертирования *.xml в *.html ???

Comment: Просто парсите в строку в index файле и с помощью echo выводите данные с нужными html тегами.

Comment: Вот именно парсить то и не получается. Надо еще цеплять его из интернета. Можно код написать, пожалуйста!

Comment: Скопировал ваш код по валютам и все работает. Какие ошибки выводит?

Comment: У меня тоже выводит в *.php, а я хочу выводить в index.html

Comment: Тогда погуглите о запуске PHP скриптов в HTML файлах.

Answer (score 1):

Всем привет!
С помощью одного опытного программиста удалось сделать все подключения! Пришлось все делать в “index.php” – работает нормально.
Также хочу сказать спасибо участнику “erm” – за сайт “openweathermap”  - отличный сайт, можно взять все что угодно про погоду в своем городе! Без рекламы.
Исходные данные:
1) Курсы валют НацБанка Кыргызстана  в формате xml - http://www.nbkr.kg/XML/daily.xml
Пример:

```html
<CurrencyRates Name="Daily Exchange Rates" Date="04.08.2017">
<Currency ISOCode="USD">
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Value>69,3250</Value>
</Currency>
<Currency ISOCode="EUR">
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Value>82,1051</Value>
</Currency>
<Currency ISOCode="KZT">
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Value>0,2063</Value>
</Currency>
<Currency ISOCode="RUB">
<Nominal>1</Nominal>
<Value>1,1411</Value>
</Currency>
</CurrencyRates>
```

2) Получение данных с сайта http://openweathermap.org/ в формате JSON.
А) Чтобы получить данные с этого сайта, надо для начала на нем зарегистрироваться. После регистрации Вам на почту придет  “API id” – он будет примерно в таком виде – “appid=7c6517cc461d80dc09aa890f55967483”
Без него получить данные невозможно, но он бесплатный.
Чтобы после регистрации получить данные о погоде надо ввести в адресную строку следующий код “http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=1528334&mode=json&units=metric&appid=7c6517cc461d80dc09aa890f55967483”
Где: id – это код Вашего города (Вы его можете сами найти на сайте), json – формат запроса, metric – градусы в Цельсия, appid – Ваш id на этом сайте. 
Получится примерно так:

```html
{"coord":{"lon":74.6,"lat":42.9},"weather":[{"id":500,"main":"Rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"}],"base":"stations","main":{"temp":18.43,"pressure":946.51,"humidity":93,"temp_min":18.43,"temp_max":18.43,"sea_level":1022.26,"grnd_level":946.51},"wind":{"speed":6.26,"deg":283.503},"rain":{"3h":0.965},"clouds":{"all":100},"dt":1501822180,"sys":{"message":0.0031,"country":"KG","sunrise":1501804554,"sunset":1501856326},"id":1528334,"name":"Bishkek","cod":200}
```

Отдельно надо скачать иконки погоды. По коду на странице можете найти путь к ее папке и через Fairfox, можно скачать их всех разом. Открываете в  Fairfox’e эту страницу, нажимаете на правую кнопку мыши, выбираете “Информация о странице”, выбираете сверху вкладку “Мультимедиа”, нажимаете ВЫДЕЛИТЬ ВСЕ и сохраняете в какой-нибудь папке!

Обработка полученных данных.
1) Курсы валют

```html
<?php     // Получаем
$document = new DomDocument();                                
$document->load('http://www.nbkr.kg/XML/daily.xml');
$nodelist = $document->getElementsByTagName('Value');
foreach($nodelist as $node) { $values[] = round (str_replace(",",".",$node->nodeValue), 2); }
?>
```

Здесь была проблема в том что получали курсы с 4 знаками после целого числа и с точкой. А нам надо было иметь 2 цифры после целого числа и запятой для обработки этих данных. Использовал функцию round для 2 цифр и str_replace для замены.

// Выводим. Здесь наоборот нужна запятая вместо точки.

```html
<div class="currency">   
<div> <b>USD</b><span><?php echo str_replace(".",",",$values[0]); ?></span></div> 
<div> <b>EUR</b><span><?php echo str_replace(".",",",$values[1]); ?></span></div> 
<div> <b>RUB</b><span><?php echo str_replace(".",",",$values[3]); ?></span></div> 
<div> <b>KZT&nbsp;</b><span><?php echo str_replace(".",",",$values[2]); ?></span></div> 
</div>
```

2) Прогноз погоды
// берем прогноз погоды

```html
$j = file_get_contents('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=1528334&mode=json&units=metric&appid=7c6517cc461d80dc09aa890f55967483'); 
$data = json_decode($j); 
  
$asd = str_replace(".",",",(round(($data->main->temp),1)));  // показания температуры. Сразу меняем точку на запятую.
$pic = $data->weather[0]->icon; // тут получаем имя картинки состояния погоды
Пояснение: $data->weather[0]->icon отличается от $data->main->temp тем что здесь weather – это массив.
```

// Выводим.

```html
<div class="block"> 
<div> <img src="images/weather2/<? echo $pic; ?>.png"></div>  <!-- Вставляем картинку погоды -->
</div> 
<div class="block3"><?php echo $asd; ?>&deg;C</div>         <!-- Вставляем температуру воздуха  -->
```

В итоге получается такая картинку в шапке: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кому чего непонятно, качайте отсюда иконки и код. https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5Uq7Wct5YVBQ1lSYXFzb0NXYUk

Всем удачи!

Comment: ВНИМАНИЕ. В данном примере неправильный “appid” – Ваш id на сайте http://openweathermap.org/.  Чтобы у Вас все нормально работало, то пройдите на сайте регистрацию – получите свой “appid” – вставьте его в пример – и у Вас ВСЕ ЗАРАБОТАЕТ!